# Script to sequentially number form input fields

Tags: javascript, php

I have some fairly large forms who's inputs need to be sequentially numbered. I need the use the sequential number twice for each field, for example...

```
<label>Label for 17</label>
<textarea name="q[17]"><?=$dataarray['q17']?></textarea>

<label>Label for 18</label>
<input type="text" name="q[18]" value="<?=$dataarray['q18']?>">

<label>Label for 19</label>
<textarea name="q[19]"><?=$dataarray['q19']?></textarea>
```

Is it possible to replace each number with a script call that will add the numbers for me? The main issue I'm having is if I need to update the forms with new fields, I need to re-number every following input manually.

I can't use a php loop as the input types vary, and I have other text and labels etc between the fields.

Comment: So you wanna generate the form dynamically from JSON via JS or directly from PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "I can't use a loop". I doubt that actually, as you could do something like:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++):
    <?php if($fieldtype == 'text'): ?>
        <input type="text" .... />
    <?php elseif($fieldtype == 'select'): ?>
        <select name="name">
           ... options
        </select>
    <?php else: ?>
         etc....
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

But anyway, if you insist, you could do this:

```
<?php $num = 1; ?>
<label>Label for <?php echo $num; ?></label>
<textarea name="q[<?php echo $num; ?>]"><?=$dataarray['q'. $num++]?></textarea>

<label>Label for <?php echo $num; ?></label>
<input type="text" name="q[<?php echo $num; ?>]" value="<?=$dataarray['q'. $num++]?>">

etc..
```

The trick is the `$num++`, use it the last time you want to print out the 'current number'. It is a [post-incrementor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), meaning it will be incremented by 1 after it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a `for()` loop inside PHP as follows:

```
function outputFields($num, $values)
{
    $html = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $html.= '<textarea name="q['.($i + 1).']">'.$values['q'.($i + 1)].'</textarea>';
    }  
    return $html;
}
```

Now, you just need to echo the returned value of this function, and pass in the number of fields to be generated, and also include the `$datearray` variable as a parameter.

For example, to output 20 fields, you can use:

```
<?php echo outputFields(20, $datearray) ?>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry my fault, the field types vary and I also have other code, labels etc between fields, so I can't use a loop to generate the fields, I just want to generate the sequential numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  echo '<textarea name="q[' . $i . ']">' . $dataarray['q' . $i] . '"></textarea>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
$max = 19; //Or whatever    
for( $i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++){ ?>
        <textarea name="q[<?php echo $i; ?>]"><?=$dataarray['q' . $i]?></textarea><?php
}
```

But you might be better doing a foreach over $dataarray.  Depends on your data structures.